# Do fixtures with relationships work in app-engine-patch?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, app-engine-patch

I have a fixture with multiple models that I'm using for testing. It 
works for the basic models, but fails to create the entities for the 
models with relationships. Is this a known limitation of app-engine-patch or am I missing 
something? I'm using JSON for the fixture file.

I'm creating the fixture file with 'manage.py dumpdata --format=json >> file.json'

Here are the models involved:

```
class BibleBook(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = db.TextProperty(required=True)

class Task(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = db.TextProperty(required=True)
    energy = db.IntegerProperty(default=1)
    focus = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    empathy = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    denarii = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    talents = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    experience = db.IntegerProperty(default=1)
    percent_per_task = db.IntegerProperty(default=5)
    bibleBook = db.ReferenceProperty(BibleBook)
    level = db.StringProperty(required=True, choices=set(["Catachumen", "Laymen", "Elder"]))
    drop_percentage = db.IntegerProperty(default=10)
```

The json in the fixture file looks like this:

```
[
{"pk": "ag5sYXctYW5kLWdvc3BlbHIcCxIWbGF3YW5kZ29zcGVsX2JpYmxlYm9vaxgDDA", 
 "model": "lawandgospel.biblebook", 
 "fields": {"name": "Luke", "description": "Description"}},

{"pk": "ag5sYXctYW5kLWdvc3BlbHIXCxIRbGF3YW5kZ29zcGVsX3Rhc2sYBQw",
 "model": "lawandgospel.task",
 "fields": {"empathy": 0, "name": "Study Luke", "level": "Catachumen", "energy": 1,
 "focus": 0, "experience": 1, "drop_percentage": 10, "talents": 0,
 "bibleBook": "ag5sYXctYW5kLWdvc3BlbHIcCxIWbGF3YW5kZ29zcGVsX2JpYmxlYm9vaxgDDA",
 "percent_per_task": 5, "denarii": 0, "description": "The Book of Luke"}}
]
```

The BibleBook model loads properly, but the Task one does not.
I'm checking this by doing:

```
books = BibleBook.gql('')
self.assertEquals(books.count(), 1)
tasks = Task.gql('')
self.assertEquals(tasks.count(), 1)
```

The first test passes, but the second does not.

Thanks,

Brian Yamabe

Comment: How did you create the fixtures? Could you provide a sample of the fixtures, including the models in which the load is failing?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, celopes, for asking for the additional code. I decided to play with the json file and fixed the problem by using simple numbers for the pk's. Here's the JSON that fixes the problem for the models and tests I posted:

```
[
{"pk": "1",
 "model": "lawandgospel.biblebook",
 "fields": {"name": "Luke", "description": "The Gospel According to St. Luke."}},

{"pk": "2",
 "model": "lawandgospel.task",
 "fields": {"empathy": 0, "name": "Study the Gospel of Luke", "level": "Catachumen",
 "energy": 1, "focus": 0, "experience": 1, "drop_percentage": 10, "talents": 0,
 "bibleBook": "1", "percent_per_task": 5, "denarii": 0,
 "description": "The Book of Luke"}}
]
```